# Restrict Find To Limited Number of Records Loop

Tags: sql, asp-classic, cdo.message

The following code works to extract the first name and email from a database and send via CDOSys and email to records found.

My hosting service limits the number of recipients to 10 so I'm thinking would it be poosible to restrict the find to the first 10 records, then send and then find the next 10 records and send and so on and so on until the end of the table is reached?

```
<%
Set OBJdbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
OBJdbConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("myData.mdb")
SQLQuery = "SELECT FirstName, Email_Address FROM MyTable" 
Set Result = OBJdbConnection.Execute(SQLQuery) 
if Not Result.EOF then 
    Do While Not Result.EOF 
        SendMail Result("FirstName"), Result("Email_Address") 
        Result.MoveNext 
    Loop 
end if 
OBJdbConnection.Close()
Set OBJdbConnection = Nothing

Sub SendMail(TheName, TheAddress)
    Dim objMessage, Rcpt
    If (TheName <> "" AND TheAddress <> "") Then
        smtpServer = "mail.mydomain.com"
        body = "Hello World"

        Rcpt = Chr(34) & TheName & Chr(34) & "<" & TheAddress & ">" 
        set objMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")  
        set cdoConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
        cdoConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        cdoConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtpServer
        cdoConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 
        cdoConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="smtp@mydomain.com"
        cdoConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="123456"
        cdoConfig.Fields.Update
        set objMessage.Configuration = cdoConfig
        objMessage.Subject = "This Month's Sales" 
        objMessage.From = """Acme Sales"" <me@mydomain.com>" 
        objMessage.To = Rcpt
        objMessage.HTMLBody = body 
        objMessage.Send
    End If
End Sub
set objMessage = Nothing
set cdoConfig = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: You'll have to make yourself clearer. The way I read it, is you're only sending 1 email at a time?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. The ISP must has some sort of flood restriction, I get an error after about 10 emails.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be what you want to do.

```
<%
if Not Result.EOF then 
i = 0
Do While  i<10
SendMail Result("FirstName"), Result("Email_Address") 
Result.MoveNext 
i= i+1
Loop
.... 
%>
```